# Filling a column in a data frame based on certain conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I am using R and RStudio.
I have the following data frame:

```
ID   TIME   DV   GpH   SIpH   GTT   SITT
1     0     0    1.4   7.1    1.8    3.5
1     1     0.5  1.4   7.1    1.8    3.5
1     2     2    1.4   7.1    1.8    3.5
1     3     5    1.4   7.1    1.8    3.5
2     0     0    1.5   7.5    0.7    2.5
2     1     0.5  1.5   7.5    0.7    2.5
2     2     2    1.5   7.5    0.7    2.5
2     3     5    1.5   7.5    0.7    2.5
```

I want to add a `pH` column to the data frame such that:

1) If `TIME` is less than `GTT` for each subject `ID` then `pH` is `GpH` for that subject.

2) If `TIME` is bigger than `GTT` and less than the sum of `GTT+SITT`  then `pH = SIpH` for that subject.

3) If `TIME` is bigger than the sum of `GTT+SITT` for each subject, then `pH=6`.

How possibly can I achieve this in R in a fast way?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried using IF statements but still wasn't able to work it out as `GTT` and `SITT` are different for each subject `ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, assuming that your data frame is stored as `df1`:

```
df1$pH <- with(df1, (TIME < GTT) * GpH + (TIME > GTT & TIME < (GTT + SITT)) * SIpH + (TIME > (GTT + SITT)) * 6)
#> df1
#  ID TIME  DV GpH SIpH GTT SITT  pH
#1  1    0 0.0 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 1.4
#2  1    1 0.5 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 1.4
#3  1    2 2.0 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 7.1
#4  1    3 5.0 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 7.1
#5  2    0 0.0 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 1.5
#6  2    1 0.5 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 7.5
#7  2    2 2.0 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 7.5
#8  2    3 5.0 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 7.5
```

Comment: Worked really well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a nesting of `ifelse`:

"Creating" the data:

```
data <- read.csv(head=TRUE, text = 
"ID,TIME,DV,GpH,SIpH,GTT,SITT
1,0,0,1.4,7.1,1.8,3.5
1,1,0.5,1.4,7.1,1.8,3.5
1,2,2,1.4,7.1,1.8,3.5
1,3,5,1.4,7.1,1.8,3.5
2,0,0,1.5,7.5,0.7,2.5
2,1,0.5,1.5,7.5,0.7,2.5
2,2,2,1.5,7.5,0.7,2.5
2,3,5,1.5,7.5,0.7,2.5")
```

Adding `ph`

```
data$ph <- ifelse(
    data$TIME < data$GTT,
      data$GpH,
      ifelse (
        data$TIME > data$GTT & data$TIME < data$GTT + data$SITT,
          data$SIpH,
          6
      )
)
```

Printing the result

```
data

  ID TIME  DV GpH SIpH GTT SITT  ph
1  1    0 0.0 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 1.4
2  1    1 0.5 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 1.4
3  1    2 2.0 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 7.1
4  1    3 5.0 1.4  7.1 1.8  3.5 7.1
5  2    0 0.0 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 1.5
6  2    1 0.5 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 7.5
7  2    2 2.0 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 7.5
8  2    3 5.0 1.5  7.5 0.7  2.5 7.5
```